# Installed angular-cookies, getting angular.module error on info function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

> Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function

[image]

I installed `angular-cookies` from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cookies via yarn: `yarn add angular-cookies`.

Added the dependency in my index like so:

```
<!-- build:vendors -->
<script src="assets/js/libs/vendors.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>

<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:bundle-js -->
<script src="assets/js/tickertags.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Then added `ngCookies` inject in my app.js

```
"use strict";
module.exports = angular.module('tickertags', [
    'templateCache',
    'tickertags-tags',     // tags / tags_module.js
    'tickertags-tickers',  // tickers / tickers_module.js
    'ngCookies',
    'ui.mask',             // https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask
    'ui.router',           // https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    'ui.bootstrap',        // https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap,
])
```

---

I also upgraded to angular 1.6.4 (from 1.5.4) and still running into this error.

Comment: sorry are you using method info() somewhere in your app ??

Comment: problem with angular dependency,

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi it's suppose to be a function inside of Angular, but I upgraded to 1.6.4 and don't see the info function anywhere in angular.js guess I can just remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was managing Angular via bower not NPM.

My bower version was `~1.5.9` and needed to bower install `angular-cookies` as well.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I am managing angular with NPM, do you think it would be safe to cut out that line from the ng-cookies module?

Comment: There are 2 kinds of developers, one that would never change code in a plugin or library they are using, and one that would. I'm in the camp that would haha... however `NPM` is suppose to manage your backend dependancies and `Bower` your frontend, and Angular falls into the frontend category.

Comment: Figured out i just needed to rollback my angular-cookies to 1.5.8 as I couldn't update my angular with angular material on the project.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the `angular-cookies` version matches your angular version.